# How to store the value of one dimension of a multidimensional array by checking the first value?

Tags: c#

In my code, I have created a Class named Combatant then I created two instances of that Class named "swastik" and "ankit" and all these instances have an integer called "index". Now, I want to initialize a Random Variable that will either return 0 or 1 as a value according to my code. Then I want to check to which instance that index value belongs that means that if the value is 0 then the Console will return swastik.firstName and if it is 1 then it will return ankit.firstName.
Most of you will probably say that use the if/else method but if I had let's say a 1000 instances of the Combatant Class, do I have to write the if/else function 1000 times?
Can anyone provide me a less complex code to do this.
My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Combat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Combatant swastik = new Combatant();
            swastik.CombatantInitialize("Swastik", "Bhattacharyya", 0);

            Combatant ankit = new Combatant();
            ankit.CombatantInitialize("Ankit", "Gupta", 1);

            Random rndIndex = new Random();

            var idxGet = rndIndex.Next(0, 2);

            Object[,] combatants = new Object[,] { { 0, swastik.index }, { 0, 1 } };
            Console.WriteLine(combatants[0,1]);
        }
    }

    class Combatant
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public string fullName;

        public int index;

        public void CombatantInitialize(string fName, string lName, int ind)
        {
            firstName = fName;
            lastName = lName;
            index = ind;
            fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `List<Combatant>` and loop over the items.

Comment: I am not so good with Arrays and Lists in C#, can you provide me a Code for this in the Answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating new items, you can add them directly to a list, try this

```
class Program
{
    List<Combatant> combatList = new List<Combatant>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Combatant swastik = new Combatant();
        swastik.CombatantInitialize("Swastik", "Bhattacharyya", 0);
        //add item to list
        combatList.Add(swastik);

        Combatant ankit = new Combatant();
        ankit.CombatantInitialize("Ankit", "Gupta", 1);
        //add item to list
        combatList.Add(ankit);

        Random rndIndex = new Random();

        var idxGet = rndIndex.Next(0, combatList.Count);
        //Output firstname to console
        Console.WriteLine(combatList[idxGet].firstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question, if I insert a bool in the class isMale and if I want to check it before initializing the WriteLine, can I use if (combatList[idxGet].isMale = True) before initializing the WriteLine?

Comment: Of course, that would work, try it out and if you encounter any problems, get back to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just put them into an array or List and use the index to access them.

```
List<Combatant> list = new List<Combatant>();
list.Add(swastik);
list.Add(ankit);
```

Since `idxGet` has the random value you want, use list like this

```
array[idxGet]
```

So your full code would be

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Combat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Combatant swastik = new Combatant();
            swastik.CombatantInitialize("Swastik", "Bhattacharyya", 0);

            Combatant ankit = new Combatant();
            ankit.CombatantInitialize("Ankit", "Gupta", 1);

            List<Combatant> list = new List<Combatant>();
            list.Add(swastik);
            list.Add(ankit);

            Random rndIndex = new Random();

            var idxGet = rndIndex.Next(0, list.Count);

            Console.WriteLine( array[idxGet].fullName );
        }
    }

    class Combatant
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public string fullName;

        public int index;

        public void CombatantInitialize(string fName, string lName, int ind)
        {
            firstName = fName;
            lastName = lName;
            index = ind;
            fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot quite understand what you are trying to say here. I am really a beginner since I am only 14. It would be very kind of you if you could provide me a complete code for this solution.

Comment: Edited, check it out.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got to check your code since I got the answer but I sure that this works too :)

Comment: Yeah, I checked it now, it surely works. Confirmed. Thanks